# SQL server log shipping - dry-run data modification script on secondary then resume log shipping

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

Am log shipping a large, busy DB from server A (primary) to server B (secondary).

Nightly backups are taken, as well as diffs every X hours, and transaction logs are shipped and restored every 15 mins.

Occasionally I need to dry-run a script on server B, to assess it's impact, before running on server B.  Script is often DDL.

I do this by taking server B out of RESTORING mode by manually executing a restore command on a recent transaction log, and testing the script.

However, to then resume log shipping, I have to restore the most recent full db, and diff, before log shipping can resume.  This is very time consuming.

On server B, is there any way to instead effectively rollback to a previous transaction log (before I tried the script), and then resume log shipping?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

> On server B, is there any way to instead effectively rollback to a
>   previous transaction log (before I tried the script), and then resume
>   log shipping?

No there is no way to do this.  You can only bring a log shipped secondary to `standby` mode.  Which allow `read_only` operations.  This is done by keeping an undo file.  When you need to restore log files again contents from the undo files are applied first.

More details about undo file here:

[In SQL server, How to see the standby file path when we restore the database in standby mode](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/batala/2011/07/20/in-sql-server-how-to-see-the-standby-file-path-when-we-restore-the-database-in-standby-mode/) by Harsh Chawla.

For testing DDL you need to bring database to `read_write` mode which will undo uncommitted transactions without keeping a log of those pages. There is no way to revert to previous state as you can do in case of `standby`.